# What causes the random explosion during spellcrafting in Ars Magica 2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So I recently started out with the Ars Arcana 2 mod on minecraft, and was working on creating my second spell; components were projectile, fire damage, ignition and color. I was working calmly and adding ingredients, but at one ingredient (I think flint and steel) the entire structure literally exploded.

I managed to crap multiple pants out of shock, and I'd like to try and avoid that. What could have caused this?

Comment: Would you provide the mod version as well as what are the 2 materials used for your crafting altar. Mainly the material most used in the structure as well as the 4 top corners

Answer (score 3):

It happens when you make too complex a spell. In your Arcane Compendium, it should say effects it adds with different blocks, if your crafting altar can only support 3 or 2 effects and you make one with 4, the book will turn red, indicating your altar isn't sufficient. If you attempt to make it anyway, your altar explodes. If you see your book turn red on the altar, remove the book, upgrade the altar, and try again

Answer (score 1):

This happens when one removes a the book or disrupts the spell's creation.

Comment: I'm afraid this was not the case. I was holding all the materials I needed before starting spell creation and was just throwing them into the spell creator in the order given.

Answer (score 1):

That might happen when the lectern makes the book turn red and the reason why this happens is when you create a bunch of random spells together. I just did that today and blew up something real important... so don't be way TOO creative on making spells.